# how to subtract one one column set of dates from another set of dates and finally add all the rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table `data` with columns `start` and `End`. The column start and end have the date and time in this format: 2012-04-06 07:43:05 . I need to do this: End - Start (for each row obviously) and add up all the resulting time. [ only time field subtraction is enough as the date is probably the same for both start and end]

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably approach this by converting the dates to unix timestamp using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in MySQL, then it is easier to do calculations like these you want.

Something like:

```
SELECT
   SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`End`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`)) AS time_sum
FROM
   data
```

This will get you a sum of all the differences in seconds.

Comment: $voice= mysql_query(" SELECT  SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_at`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_at`)) FROM  call_sessions ");
$voice_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($voice);
echo $voice_row;


Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work if you add the `AS time_sum` I edited into my answer and then do `echo $voice_row['time_sum']`, forgot to give the new column a decent name so it's usable in PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(timediff(`start`, `end`)) as diff_sum
from your_table
```

Comment: Does this return the sum of time diff of all the rows?
Or is it againa column with set of rows with the time diff of the respective rows

Comment: I added a `sum` to the query. Now it will add all time diffs up.

Answer (score 0):

you could use datediff to gets days, or timediff to get a time like '01:23:45',
or my favorite unix timestamps that returns number of secounds

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) AS sec
```

Comment: Does this return the sum of time diff of all the rows?

Comment: this give the secounds for that row, if you want the sum use `SUM()` as in SilverSnakes exemple/answer

Comment: $voice= mysql_query(" SELECT  SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end_at`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_at`)) FROM  call_sessions ");
$voice_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($voice);
echo $voice_row;
 is this correct? As i am not getting yet.....should i add anything more?

Comment: `$voice_row` is a array, add an `AS fieldname`, and at your `echo $voice_row['fieldname']`